# $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}$$

As part of a larger problem, I'm trying to evaluvate this summation
now I know
$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!}=e$$
but is there anyway I can use that?
I was thinking of re-writing it as $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)+1}{(n-1)!}=2e $$
but that's assuming

$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-a)!}=e  $$
if a is a finite real

but I'm not sure how to prove that

Please note the only thing I know about series expansions is the taylor series, I don't know anything about tests of convergence, radius of convergence etc

Comment: How have you managed to learn about Taylor series without learning about convergence tests for series?

Comment: Here in India all most teachers care about is this thing called JEE. I was able to extract the formula for the general expansion around zero from my teacher, but he wouldn't explain anymore.

Comment: could someone please explain the downvotes. I'd like to learn hw to improve in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence isn't relevant here, as it 'obviously' converges and you want to evaluate it. My telling you it converges isn't enough!

But it's not too bad. Just do some 'jiggery pokery'. $$\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^2}{n!}&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}\\&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!}\\&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\\&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{n!}\\&=2e\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! So basically the contributions of the terms as we tend to infinity is negligible, right?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever Not 'negligible' as in: "can be ignored". Why do you ask? That has nothing to do with evaluation

Comment: I'm just finding it hard to accept two sums that differ by a constant number of terms tend to the same value

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever I'm not sure what you're comparing. Do you mean, $\sum\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n!}$? It's important to record where these are indexed from

Comment: oh,Ok. Didn't notice that . Understood. Thanks!